# Retrieve function arguments as a tuple in C++

Tags: c++, function, tuples

Consider I have a function declarations like these:

```
void foo(int x, float y);

class X {
  void anotherFoo(double a, int c);
};
```

How can I get a tuple that corresponds to the function arguments? In the above case it would be:

```
boost::tuple<int, float>
boost::tuple<X*, double, int>
```

or even better with the result type as 0th element:

```
boost::tuple<void, int, float>
boost::tuple<void, X*, double, int>
```

I know that `boost::function_types::parameter_types` can do exactly this. However, I am interested in the principle of how it is implemented.

Comment: I would use a `struct`. What is the aim / advantage of using tuples?

Comment: @kol less boilerplate code, less noise

Comment: Do you mean you want to auto-generate the tuple type at compile time or run-time, or you want to extract the parameters from the regs / stack, or both, or something else?

Comment: It should be all compile time - I just need the parameters as a struct/tuple so that I can use them in metaprogramming.

Comment: Have you tried to read boost sources?

Comment: @alex: Yes :( It's too complicated to understand just by reading. Too many indirections and zero comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the tuple *type* corresponding to your argument *types*, like this:

```
template <typename R, typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> function_args(R (*)(T...))
{
    return std::tuple<T...>();
}

// get the tuple type
typedef decltype(function_args(foo)) FooArgType;
// create a default-initialised tuple
auto args = function_args(foo);
```

Is that what you want?
Note you may need to add one or more overloads of `function_args`, eg. taking a class type param for class methods.

Comment: Does the `decltype` still work if the function can't be instantiated because one or more of its parameter types can't be default-initialized? And if not, is there some workaround with a pointer that would do it?

Comment: You can still use the `decltype(function_args(foo))` in a typedef or whatever, but you can never really _call_ `function_args` in that case.

Comment: This works, thanks. Is there a way to avoid decltype (as this is C++11 only)? Boost works even on non-C++11 compilers so this should be achievable somehow.

Comment: I guess you can return a helper class instance with the tuple typedef'd: then you're just using the template function type deduction to save writing out the helper class type parameters. Note the variadic template syntax is also C++11 only - if you can't use it, I think you're looking at lots of overloads for different numbers of arguments.

Comment: @Useless: How can I achieve that tuple typedef without decltype? I am aware that I'll have to provide lots of overloads for older compilers but I guess there's no way around that.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way how to do this in C++03 using partial specialization. A lot of overloads for different number of arguments and const/volatile functions are necessary but the idea is following:

```
/* An empty template struct, this gets chosen if the given template parameter is not a member function */
template <typename _Func>
struct MemberFunctionInfo {  };

/* Specialization for parameterless functions */
template <typename _Result, typename _Class>
struct MemberFunctionInfo<_Result (_Class::*) ()>  {
    typedef _Class class_type;
    typedef _Result result_type;
    typedef boost::tuple<> parameter_types;
    enum { arity = 0 };
};

/* Specialization for parameterless const functions */
template <typename _Result, typename _Class>
struct MemberFunctionInfo<_Result (_Class::*) () const> : MemberFunctionInfo<_Result (_Class::*) ()> { };

/* Specialization for functions with one parameter */
template <typename _Result, typename _Class, typename P0>
struct MemberFunctionInfo<_Result (_Class::*) (P0)>  {
    typedef _Class class_type;
    typedef _Result result_type;
    typedef boost::tuple<P0> parameter_types;
    enum { arity = 1 };
};

/* Specialization for const functions with one parameter */
template <typename _Result, typename _Class, typename P0>
struct MemberFunctionInfo<_Result (_Class::*) (P0) const> : MemberFunctionInfo<_Result (_Class::*) (P0)> { };

.
.
.
```

Example usage:

```
template <typename MemFunc>
int getArity(MemFunc fn)  {
  // Can also use MemberFunctionInfo<MemFunc>::parameter_types with boost::mpl
  return MemberFunctionInfo<MemFunc>::arity;
}
```

The above solution has some flaws. It doesn't handle function references, non-member functions or `volatile`/`const volatile` member functions but it's easy to account for these by adding more specializations.

For C++11, the approach mentioned by @Useless is way cleaner and should be preferred.